# Docker: unable to install php intl extention when using php:fpm-alpine official image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am setting up very basic Docker container for a PHP and Zend framework project. I am using official Docker image `php:fpm-alpine`. Container is running successfully and I am able to see my application. In order for Zend to work I need PHP `intl` extention. When I add `RUN docker-php-ext-install intl` command in `DockerFile` extention is not installed successfully.

DockerFile code

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql intl
```

Any help or recommendation is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42):

The installation of `intl` extension is failing because a dependency is missing for it.  Please update your Dockerfile with following and it should work.

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine    
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apk add icu-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you Sandeep for the simple and effective solution!

Comment: Thanks, was pulling my hair with this for hours. Wait.. I have no hair I'm bald :D

Comment: It's work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Is the install _mysqli pdo pdo_mysql_ could be done in the same intl install :  ```RUN apk add icu-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql intl``` ?

Comment: YES (at my previous question !-)

Comment: You don't need to run `docker-php-ext-configure intl`.

Comment: Worked in my Symfony 6.1 Dockerfile. I removed the `intl` from the `install-php-extensions zip intl apcu opcache` line and added your `RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl;` right behind. Ofcourse then do rebuild of the images.  And I did do the install of symfony/intl via composer, as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html)

Comment: Need to restart container if installing from inside of it